# Regular expressions in PHP behave strangely

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

So, I've got some kind of database and I use regular expressions to process all those lines. But the problem is there may be no or not single '@' symbol in email section. I decided to put @ before domain(there are not many of them) and then just remove all the @'s I don't need.
I use some online regular expressions constructors - like this one http://www.phpliveregex.com/ . I got following regular expression for putting @ before domain:

```
preg_replace("/(dodgit|trashymail|pookmail|spambob|mailinator)/", "@$1", $myline);
```

But it just doesn't work. For example:

```
CynthiaELopezdodgit.com
```

doesn't change after this script.

What can be wrong? I'm new to PHP so sorry if the problem is really stupid :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to get the return value

```
$newLine = preg_replace("/(dodgit|trashymail|pookmail|spambob|mailinator)/", "@$1", $myline);
```

$newLine will contain the email with the @, $myline will continue to hold the one without.  preg_replace does not mutate the original variable

Answer (score 2):

Your regex works fine. I would check to make sure you're looking at the right variable. `preg_replace` doesn't overwrite the variable, but instead returns it.

For a working example: http://codepad.org/PSxK7Jtv